# Font size of some sections in toc smaller than others

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, fontsize

I am using the  `article` class with a rather standard setup in LyX. In my TOC some sections with longer titles are displayed with a smaller font size even though there is enough space to the page number on the right.

I would even prefer to display the section title in two lines than adapting it in the table of contents. How can I achieve a consistent font size?

(I am using hyperref)

Example image can be found here
[image]

Comment: [welcome to TeX.SE!](http://goo.gl/PiJ21)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *always* helps if you post a small example document that shows the problem.

However LaTeX would not do that by default so my guess is that you have a size command such as `\small` in the section heading. That's wrong; you don't want formatting commands in the head. Note also you can supply a separate shorter title for the toc as

```
\subsection[short title]{very very long title}
```

Comment: Now I am not wondering any longer why google wouldn't show me any similar problems… I expected that to be an automatic adaption in LaTeX and didn't double check on custom font sizing of the heading, which, however, is a bit harder to identify in LyX. Thank you @David !

Comment: Didn't know that the short title optional arguments existed for subsection.. cheers.